# Looking up ApplicationUser in each controller action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

I am writing an ASP.Net Core Web Application, using the template as my starting point. I have added a couple of custom fields to my `ApplicationUser` which have an impact on what data I return from my controller actions.

At the moment I am doing the following in each controller where I need to look up these fields:

```cs
ApplictionUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

This works fine, but I am wondering if this is the correct way to go about this; making a db lookup in every action for the user details or should I be caching the retrieved user in some way?

Comment: It is up to you. if you don't have noticable performance issues, it is fine to keep it like this.

Comment: as Ruikai said you could try the Caching  to retrieved user details can it can improve the performance of your application by reducing the number of database queries. you try In-Memory Cache, Distributed Cache, or Custom User Claims approaches. Custom User Claims add the custom fields as claims to the user's identity during authentication  This way, you can access the custom fields directly from the User object without making a database query.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't  need to update the user info in Db  frequently ,you could cache the receviced user following the [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0)